# stringr will not install in R

Tags: r, stringr

I'm having issues installing `stringr`. Here's what I get when I request an install of stringr:

```
utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
also installing the dependency ‘stringi’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:

        binary source needs_compilation

stringi  1.1.5  1.1.6              TRUE

stringr  1.2.0  1.3.0             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_1.1.5.zip'

Content type 'application/zip' length 14220135 bytes (13.6 MB)
downloaded 13.6 MB

package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpsjXf2p\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘stringr’


trying URL 'https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/stringr_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118333 bytes (115 KB)
downloaded 115 KB

* installing *source* package 'stringr' ...
** package 'stringr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
namespace 'stringi' 1.1.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.6 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'stringr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringr'

Thank you for any help you might provide.
```

Comment: this is the issue with most of the industries , they dont provide latest version of R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R community generally [doesn't support old versions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Package-xxx-is-out-of-date-for-Windows). The last release in the 3.2 series was almost two years ago. Updating to the latest stable release is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the error message that:

```
'stringi' 1.1.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.6 is required
```

And also when it installed `stringi` it said that:

```
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
```

---

So, you need to force the install of the source package. Try this:

```
utils:::menuInstallPkgs(type="source")
```

Or just

```
install.packages("stringr", type="source")
```

Comment: miken32...thank you. Followed your recommendations.  Still had a few hiccups (like..."ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glue'"), but individually installed "glue" and finally get stringr working. Again thank you.